# "I'm asking you to middle a diamond"

Tags: meaning, verbs, american-english, north-american-english

In the movie Donnie Brasco, Al Pacino shows a jeweler a diamond and tells him

> "I'm asking you to middle a diamond for me here."

What does it mean "to middle"?

I cannot found 'middle' as a verb in any English dictionary-only as an adjective or noun.

Comment: Perhaps he wanted the jeweler to act as middleman, to sell the diamond by acting as broker between (middle) Donnie and the consumer.

Comment: It sounds like informal verbification to me. *Google* never used to be verb, only the name of a company. But because people kept using it as a verb it became one.

Comment: And “middle” is so much less scary than “fence”, which is so clearly illegal.

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly, ***middle*** (verb) is *not* found in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/middle), or in Merriam Webster. Those two references usually cover "across the pond" differences in semantics.

However..

a ***middleman*** (noun) is...

> an intermediary or agent between two parties especially : a dealer, agent, or company intermediate between the producer of goods and the retailer or consumer

[-Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/middleman)

The slang usage has evolved as a form of verbification, and is understood in certain quarters to mean 'act as a middleman'. I have heard the expression  used, and have used it for over 40 years, in various business environments. In my opinion, it is quite established in American English.

I cannot speak for BrE. usage.